# I cannot fill the lines with color. It simply makes them black

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to make a draw simulation, but it is not working. I made sure that colors[penColorsIndex] is right and I am not getting any errors. Can anyone help? When I call drawLines(lineArray), the color is black. So, it then shows only black lines instead of red, green, or yellow lines.

```
var lineObj = {
        px: pmouseX,
        py: pmouseY,
        x: mouseX,
        y: mouseY,
        c: colors[penColorsIndex],
        size: penSizes[penSizesIndex]
    };
lines.push(lineObj);

function drawLines(lineArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
         fill(lineArray[i].c);
         strokeWeight(lineArray[i].size)
         line(lineArray[i].px, lineArray[i].py, lineArray[i].x, lineArray[i].y);
    }


};
```

Comment: where you are calling `drawLines(lineArray)`  and what is `lineArray`

Comment: Where are `fill`, `strokeWeight`, and `line` defined?

Comment: @Suchit My guess is he's calling `drawLines(lines)` somewhere.

Comment: To all of your questions:    I call drawLines(lineArray) somewhere else in the program. I am using a library to do this, since this is a drawing program and I do not want to waste my time writing all the code for them.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can properly understand the question.

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation of the drawing library. How are we supposed to know what you're doing wrong if we don't know how the library is supposed to be used. And make a jsfiddle or stack snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you setting `penColorsIndex` before you assign `lineObj`? The object won't be updated if you change the variable later.

Comment: @Barmar [http://p5js.org/reference/](http://p5js.org/reference/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you show use `stroke()` instead of `fill()`.

```
stroke(lineArray[i].c);
strokeWeight(lineArray[i].size)
line(lineArray[i].px, lineArray[i].py, lineArray[i].x, lineArray[i].y);
```

stroke is for the border, fill is for the background.